# Can I use a local file as a source in a live page?

Tags: html

I like to use JSFiddle when designing a new interface because I find it convenient for various tools within. I'm working on the front end of a site where I want to use a video, and unlike an image, I cant just throw it up on imgur and link to it for free instant hosting while I fiddle with the interface design.

So I want to know if I can somehow use a local file on my PC as the source for an HTML video element hosted on a live site. Obviously this is trivial to do with a web project being worked on on my Desktop, but I'm not sure it can be done on a live test.

For example this would work on a page I open from my desktop, living on my PC:

```
<video id="Video-Player">
    <source src="../movie.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
```

But I don't know whether I can do the equivalent with a page living on the web.

Comment: Just upload it to youtube or something?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I'm actually trying to use the video as a background in the design, and while I know that to be possible, it's not applicable in my situation since my end goal is to stream various videos from my site to the player based on user input.

Comment: Anyhow, using local file from web page is likely to be impossible (because of browser security). It'd be a huge issue if any web site could just load arbitrary files from your FS, wouldn't it?

Comment: You can load a video from ones local machine if the user finds the video through the same popup interface that one would use pick a file to upload.  (couldn't come up with an actual name for that popup window). Is this what you want to do?

Comment: @Mr.Me That's a good idea, although it wasnt what I originally imagined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to allow a user to select an image from their local machine. This should get you started in the right direction.

Add a file input button in the HTML

```
<input type="file" id="file-btn"/>
```

and the corresponding handler

```
document.getElementById('file-btn').addEventListener('change', function(e){
  readFiles(e.target.files);
})
```

Then the code to read the files

```
function readFiles(files){
  files = [].slice.call(files); //turning files into a normal array

  for (var file of files){
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = createOnLoadHandler(file);
    //there are also reader.onerror reader.onloadstart, reader.onprogress, and reader.onloadend handlers

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}
```

Now, I've only done this with images, but this is how I read the image data.

```
function createOnLoadHandler(file){
  console.log('reading ' + file.name + ' of type ' + file.type)

  function onLoad(e){
    var data = e.target.result
    display(data);
  }

  return onLoad
}

function display(data){

    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = data;

    var context = canvas.getContext('2d')
    context.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
  }
```

[Here is a demo](http://mrme.me/lio/blog/demos/basic-example.html) of the above code.

As a side note, if you try to read images from another domain you'll run into [cross origin policy](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) issues. I would think the same problem exists for videos as well.